# How to connect Ms access 2010 (.accdb ) database with odbc driver

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ado.net, windows

Can any one tell how to connect Ms access 2010 (.accdb ) database with odbc driver in c# and .NET 4.0

I tried

```
string connetionString = ("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb*.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\New folder\\MatchDetails.accdb;");

OdbcConnection myConnection = new OdbcConnection(connetionString);

try
{                   
    myConnection.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Connection Open ! ");
    myConnection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
}
```

throwing this Exception

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified exception

Comment: What version of Ace are you using..12.0?

Comment: For Acces databases (.mdb, .accdb, etc...), you want to use [OleDbConnection][1], like this:

   ` conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\New folder\\MatchDetails.accdb;");`

Comment: Ram, did you ever get this to work? Trying to connect a Python script via OLEDB to MS Access 2010 64-bit, I get the 'Provider not found' error. I downloaded and installed the AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe, then pointed odbc data sources to %Win%/SysWOW64 but to no avail. What is remarkable, I can connect to a Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0 for any .mdb file. Just can't connect to an .accdb file. Epic frustration!

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo in your [connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access):

```
string connectionString = ("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\New folder\\MatchDetails.accdb;");
```

(note the comma in the Driver name)

Comment: Please don't hesitate to fix the typo in the variable name.  Good typing skills is 30% of the programmer's job, isn't it?

Comment: Good call.  I didn't catch that in my copy/paste

Answer (score 0):

I see a two typos in driver name:

1. There is no space before the brackets
2. There is no comma inside the brackets

Correct connection string:

```
string connectionString = ("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\New folder\\MatchDetails.accdb;");
```